# TypeError: message.guild.roles.cache.array is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

Actually, I don't know how to fix my code anymore, I tried a lot, but I can't solve the problem yet

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });
const AsciiTable = require("ascii-data-table").default;
const prefix = "#";

client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {
    if (!message.guild || !message.channel || message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "roles")) {
        var
            ros = message.guild.roles.cache.size,
            data = [["Rank", "RoleName"]]
            for(let i = 0; i < ros; i++) {
                if(message.guild.roles.cache.array()[i].id !== message.guild.id) {
                    data.push([i,`${message.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => r.position == ros-i).map(r=>r.name)}`])
        }
            }
        let res = AsciiTable.table(data)
        message.channel.send({ content: `**\`\`\`xl\n${res}\`\`\`**` });
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: before the last nested if please put a console.log(message.guild.roles.cache) to see if there is any method by name array or not?

Comment: Just small FYI, intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change from `message.guild.roles.cache.array()` to `[...message.guild.roles.cache.values()]`

Here is what the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#collection) said:

> These methods existed to provide access to a cached array of Collection values and keys respectively, which other Collection methods relied on internally. Those other methods have been refactored to no longer rely on cache, so those arrays and these methods have been removed.
> You should instead construct an array by spreading the iterators returned by the base Map class methods